# Constraint warnings when trying to load YouTube Videos from a webview

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to load a YouTube video with a webview. The video plays fine and exactly how I want it, but the debugger keeps throwing out warnings (see the end). This warning is repeated for about 20 times.

I tried to isolate the problem and made a new ViewController without any constraints and it still shows constrain related warnings.

I tried to play with `.translatesAutoresizingMask` and `.scalesToFitPage` but they don't seem to make a difference.

This is the code I use to embed the video:

```
// webView from an IBOutlet in an empty ViewController without any constraints

func playVideo(){

    var staticUrlString = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jNQXAC9IVRw"
    var youtubeVideoId = NSString(string: staticUrlString)
    var rng: NSRange = youtubeVideoId.rangeOfString("&feature=")

    if(rng.length>0){
        youtubeVideoId = youtubeVideoId.stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(NSMakeRange(rng.location, youtubeVideoId.length-rng.location), withString: "")
    }

    youtubeVideoId = youtubeVideoId.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=", withString: "")
    youtubeVideoId = youtubeVideoId.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=", withString: "")

    var youTubeVideoHTML: NSString = NSString(format: "<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><style>body{margin:0px 0px 0px 0px; background:#1111}</style></head> <body> <div id=\"player\"></div> <script> var tag = document.createElement('script'); tag.src = \"http://www.youtube.com/player_api\"; var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag); var player; function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() { player = new YT.Player('player', { width:'%0.0f', height:'%0.0f', videoId:'%@', events: { 'onReady': onPlayerReady, 'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange } });} function onPlayerReady(event) { event.target.playVideo(); } function onPlayerStateChange(event) {if(event.data === 0) {   event.target.destroy(); }}  </script> </body> </html>",0.0, 0.0,youtubeVideoId)

    //webView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints()
    //webView.scalesPageToFit = false
    webView.mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction = false
    webView.opaque = false

    webView.loadHTMLString(youTubeVideoHTML, baseURL: NSURL(string: NSString(format: "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=%@", youtubeVideoId)))


    println("play")
}
```

This is one of the warnings:

```
Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7cb37910 UIImageView:0x7cb36fb0.centerX == AVUnsupportedContentIndicatorView:0x7cb36cf0.centerX>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7cb37d70 H:[UIImageView:0x7cb36fb0]-(>=10)-|   (Names: '|':AVUnsupportedContentIndicatorView:0x7cb36cf0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7cb4f430 H:|-(0)-[AVUnsupportedContentIndicatorView:0x7cb36cf0]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7cb36b20 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7cb4f460 H:[AVUnsupportedContentIndicatorView:0x7cb36cf0]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7cb36b20 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7cb4f310 H:|-(0)-[UIView:0x7cb36b20]   (Names: '|':AVPlayerView:0x7cb36860 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7cb4f360 H:[UIView:0x7cb36b20]-(0)-|   (Names: '|':AVPlayerView:0x7cb36860 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7cb5ef40 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' H:[AVPlayerView:0x7cb36860(1)]>"
)


Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7d342240 UIView:0x7d229b90.centerX == AVExternalPlaybackIndicatorView:0x7d22a150.centerX>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't seem like the constraints you get warnings about are related to views you created directly — they're about Apple's internal view structure.

This is (most likely) a bug. You should file a report here: https://bugreport.apple.com.

Comment: Would these warnings lessen my chance to get my app approved? I might look into the official YouTube video helper, but that's quite a bit of extra I'd have to work in.

Comment: No. It's a good idea to pay attention to warnings, but they won't get your app rejected.